# Shorthand way to mutate across columns similar to excel drag where fields to be e.g. divided contain similar names?

Tags: r

A data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  cohort = seq(ymd('2020-01-01'), ymd('2020-01-31'), by = "1 days"),
  spend = rnorm(31, 100, 10),
  revenue_d1 = rnorm(31, 10, 3),
  revenue_d2 = rnorm(31, 15, 3),
  revenue_d3 = rnorm(31, 20, 3),
  bla_d1 = rnorm(31, 5, 1),
  bla_d2 = rnorm(31, 5, 1),
  bla_d3 = rnorm(31, 5, 1)
)
```

I would like to mutate 3 more fields that are the quotient of the bla fields over their corresponding revenue fields.

My current plan is just:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(blah_over_rev_d1 = bla_d1 / revenue_d1,
         blah_over_rev_d2 = bla_d2 / revenue_d2,
         blah_over_rev_d3 = bla_d3 / revenue_d3)
```

However my real df has many more fields and this would be repetitive. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume the columns 'bla' and 'revenue' occur in the same order for corresponding case, just subset the columns of interest and divide by the corresponding subset dataset, assign (`<-`) to create new columns in `base R`

```
nm1 <- grep('^bla', names(df), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- grep('^revenue', names(df), value = TRUE)
df[sub("_", "_over_rev_", nm1)] <- df[nm1]/df[nm2]
```

---

In `tidyverse`, an option would be `map2` to loop over the two sets of datasets, `/`, and then bind with the original dataset

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map2_dfr(df %>% 
          select(starts_with('bla')),
        df %>% 
           select(starts_with('revenue')), `/`) %>% 
    rename_all(~ str_replace(., '_', '_over_rev_')) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `split.default` :

```
remove_cols <- c(1, 2)
cbind(df, sapply(split.default(df[-remove_cols], 
                 sub('.*_', '', names(df)[-remove_cols])), 
                 function(x) x[[2]]/x[[1]]))

#       cohort spend revenue_d1 revenue_d2 revenue_d3 bla_d1 bla_d2 bla_d3    d1    d2    d3
#1  2020-01-01  82.5      13.39      16.11       21.3   5.78   3.93   6.40 0.432 0.244 0.300
#2  2020-01-02  91.8       8.42      15.73       20.6   7.30   5.45   5.90 0.867 0.347 0.287
#3  2020-01-03 100.6      15.00      11.96       16.0   5.16   4.79   3.35 0.344 0.400 0.210
#4  2020-01-04 103.0       6.58      12.63       20.0   5.05   5.31   5.23 0.767 0.421 0.261
#5  2020-01-05  92.4      10.43      15.90       19.3   5.10   4.91   6.65 0.489 0.309 0.344
#6  2020-01-06 126.8       6.70      19.92       20.0   5.07   6.07   6.42 0.757 0.305 0.321
#...
#...
```

Using `sub` we keep only the part of the columns names which need to divided together.

```
sub('.*_', '', names(df)[-remove_cols])
#[1] "d1" "d2" "d3" "d1" "d2" "d3"
```

So here column 1 and 4 form 1 group, column 2 and 5 another and so on. This grouping is used to split the data column-wise in `split.default`.